# Linq NHibernate Query Subitems

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fetch

I need to get some informations, but I am new in NHibernate

I have classes like:

```
Person
   Id
   IdAddress
   Address

Address
   Id
   IdCity
   City
   IdNeighborhood
   Neighborhood
```

and classes

```
City
Neighborhood
```

I need all address with a neighboorhood id,
This code is where I search the information, but here only get the city:

```
using(var session = openSession()){
   var q = session.Query<Person>(a => Id == IdSearch)
           .Fetch(a => a.Address)
           .ThenFetch(a => a.City)
           .ToList();
   session.Clear();
}
```

How could I also get neighboorhood information?

Comment: Is `Neighborhood` a class? Or just a string?

Comment: Yes, I edited the post with more information about the problem

Comment: How are you determining Neighborhood is empty? Your checking before `Session.Clear()` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer,
In the query, need to be in this way:

```
using(var session = openSession()){
    var q = session.Query<Person>(a => Id == IdSearch)
       .Fetch(a => a.Address)
       .ThenFetch(a => a.City)
       .Fetch(a => a.Address)//search address again to have access to neighboorhoor
       .ThenFetch(a => a.Neighborhood)
       .ToList();
    session.Clear();
}
```